# Batch convert images files jpg, png to webp also in subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, image, webp

I have found a script to convert files in a directoy
but I need this with subdirectors

Can you help me ?

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

# cd to the directory of the image so we can work with just filenames
dir="$(dirname "$1")"
cd "$dir" || exit 1
base="$(basename "$1" .png)"

# create a WebP version of the PNG
cwebp -q 80 "$base".png -o "$base".webp

# delete the WebP file if it is equal size or larger than the original PNG
if [[ `stat -c '%s' "$base".webp` -ge `stat -c '%s' "$base".png` ]]; then
    echo "Deleting WebP file that is no smaller than PNG"
    rm -f "$base".webp
fi

# delete the WebP file if it is size 0
if [[ -f "$base".webp && ! -s "$base".webp ]]; then
    echo "Deleting empty WebP file"
    rm -f "$base".webp
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Good news: You won't be have to change the script!

you can find all directories inside the root dir by the command:

```
find /path/to/root/dir -type d
```

and you can add execute of some command for each found dir:

Assuming your script name is **script.sh** and it is located in your home dir, and you want to run it on all sub dirs under current dir (include the current dir):

```
find . -type d -exec ~/script.sh "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when trying to find jpg images in a directory tree.  The `tree` command helped me greatly.  Below is sample code I used to iterate through all directories and only function on those with jpg images.

```
tree -dfi ${dir_name} | sed 's/$/\//g' | while read line
do
  if [ `ls "${line}" | grep -ci jpg` -gt 0 ]
  then
    some code
  fi
done
```

In your case you could grep for only PNG or perhaps do both jpg and png.  One other option would be find commands using the file name and output to a while loop

```
find ${dir_name} -type f -name "*.jpg" | while read line
do
  some code
done
```